# Workbox routing.registerRoute idempotence

Tags: workbox

What happens when you register the same RegExp pattern multiple times? 
I have tried to find a way to check if the route pattern is already registered with no luck so I ended up just registering the same route multiple times.
I'm wondering if it has any side effects.

Answer (score 4):

The first matching route "wins", and nothing in particular will happen if you register multiple identical routes.

It's not exactly what you asked, but in general, if you have multiple routes, and some are more specific than others, list the more specific ones first so that they will take precedence. E.g.

```
// Do this:

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('^/path/to/something'),
  someHandler
);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('^/path/to/'),
  someOtherHandler
);
```

As opposed to

```
// Don't do this;
// the first route will match everything that the second route matches,
// so the second route will never be used.

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('^/path/to/'),
  someHandler
);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('^/path/to/something'),
  someOtherHandler
);
```